# inputのvalueが取得できない

Tags: javascript, html

検索ボックスでエンターキーを押した時に入力された値を元に検索をかけるという処理があります。
下記htmlをヘッダー内に2つ　記載しているのですが、menu-search-wrap-hdクラスの検索ボックスで値が取得できないという状況に陥っています。
javascriptは通っています。
クラスぐらいしか2つの際はないように感じるのですが、何が原因で値が取れないのかが不明です。
どなたかご教授いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

```html
<div class="menu-search-wrap">
    <label>
        <input type="text" data-id="<{$search_form.keyword_id}>" value="<{$search.keyword}>" placeholder="アイテムを検索" class="search-keyword">
    </label>
    <a href="<{$search_form.search_url}>" class="menu-search-btn search-url"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a>
</div>

中略

<div class="menu-search-wrap-hd">
　　　　<label>
　　　　　　　　<input type="text" data-id="<{$search_form.keyword_id}>" value="<{$search.keyword}>" placeholder="アイテムを検索" class="search-keyword">
　　　　</label>
　　　　<a href="<{$search_form.search_url}>" class="menu-search-btn-hd search-url"> <img src="https://hogehoge.com" class="sample3Img"></a>
</div>
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('.search-keyword').on('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var index = $('.search-keyword').index(this);
            $('.search-url')[index].click();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: 値を取るコードも見せてください。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。無知で申し訳ないのですが、上のjavascriptではvalueの値は取れてないということでしょうか？javascriptの部分で取得できていると思っていたのですが。。。

Comment: 提示されているコードでは、テキストフィールドでEnterキーが押されたら対応するリンクをクリックしているだけで、値は何もしていないように見えます。何かのフレームワークで値をどうにかする仕組みがあるのかもしれません。

Comment: <{$search.keyword}>の部分で値を取ってきてる可能性があります。利用しているECサイトの変数なので裏で起きていることはこちらでは把握できない状況です。例えばですが<{$search.keyword}>の変数を使わずに独自の関数を作成して入力された値をvalueにセットできれば問題はないでしょうか？

Comment: 任意のJavaScriptを置ける環境ならできそうですが、これ以上は第三者がアドバイスするのは難しいですね。

Comment: 任意のjavascriptは置くことは可能なので、その案で行ってみます。ありがとうございました。